# how do I pipe with use Parallel::ForkManager?

Tags: perl, fork, pipe

I want to have children processes write to the parent's @array. I've read about piping but I'm very confused on how to actually implement it:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
my @array;
my $pm=new Parallel::ForkManager(3); 

    for((1..5)){
    $pm->start and next; 
    print "child: ".$_."\n";
    push(@array,$_); # what do I do here to put it into the parent's @array????
    $pm->finish; 
    }
$pm->wait_all_children;


print "parent: ".$_."\n" for @array;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use pipes, then you need to create a pair of pipes before you spawn each child, write to the writing pipe from the child, and use [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Select) to read from all of the reading ends in parallel in the parent. You'll also need to change the way you wait for the children, since ForkManager's `wait_all_children` is blocking, which isn't very useful. You could use a `run_on_start` method to register each process in a hash and a `run_on_finish` method to delete each process after it dies, and then terminate the select loop when no processes are remaining.

Or, if it's not important that the children can pass their results back to the parent in realtime, you can use ForkManager's ability to pass data back to the parent on exit through the `finish` call, which would look something like:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

# No indirect object notation
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(3);
my @array;
$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
    my $return = $_[5]; # Count 'em.
    push @array, @$return;
});

for(1..5) {
  $pm->start and next;
  print "child: $_\n";
  $pm->finish(0, [$_]);
}

$pm->wait_all_children;

print "parent: $_\n" for @array;
```

which actually works.

Comment: Nice; the second argument to finish is new and not in the year-old version I have installed, but it makes a lot of sense that this functionality is incorporated into P::FM itself.

Comment: I fully reflect ysth's sentiment. Someone used that second argument in partial code I saw recently, and I didn't clue in that P::FM itself was handling it. It didn't exist last time I looked at P::FM. Thanks!

Comment: Really helpful answer- thanks. May be worth noting explicitly that the 5th argument to the sub in run_on_finish always contains the datastructure. my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $data_structure_reference) = @_;